# PHP API Response convert array to JSON returns empty values

Tags: php, json, laravel

I am using Laravel to access an external API. In my controller I get the desired response array:

`$response = $this->api->accounts()->list();`

I can see the array if I do:
`dd($response);`

If I try

`return $response;`

it gives me

`[{ },{ },{ },{ },{ },{ },{ },{ }]`

I have tried encoding it

`return json_encode($response);`

and get the same empty JSON.

How can I take the API response and turn it into a JSON object or a laravel collection object so that I can parse it?

[image: Result if I dd($response)]

Comment: This means that `AccountData` does not implement `JsonSerializable` and the members seen there are all private so they are not exposed when it gets converted to json. If you wrote those classes you should probably change then and if not then consult the documentation of whoever wrote them on how to get those fields exposed so you can write some custom code to covert them to an array.

Comment: Interesting find. I will reach out to the developer. I was trying to avoid the process of doing a foreach loop and rebuilding the collection into a usable JSON array